# Merging results from belongsToMany and belongsTo relationships in Eloquent

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

In my `Image` model I have two relationships with my `Article` model, one many-to-many and one one-to-many:

```
public function articlesAlbums()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Article', 'article_image', 'image_id', 'article_id')->publishedFilter();
}

public function articleThumb()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Article')->publishedFilter();
}
```

I merge the results from these to get all images used by `Article`:

```
public function getArticlesAllAttribute()
{
    return $this->articlesAlbums->merge($this->articleThumb);
}
```

In my `Article` model I have two relationships with my `Image` model:

```
public function images()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Image', 'article_image', 'article_id', 'image_id');
}

public function thumbnail()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Image', 'image_id');
}
```

I would like to merge these as well, same way I do in my `Image` model:

```
public function getImagesAllAttribute()
{
    return $this->images->merge($this->thumbnail);
}
```

But that doesn't work, it seems to be because my thumbnail relationship is `belongsTo`, not `hasMany`. So maybe it's not a collection. When I try I get an exception:

```
Call to a member function getKey() on a non-object
```

I've tried converting it to a collection with:

```
new Collection($this->thumbnail)
```

but get an error saying:

```
__construct() must be of the type array, object given
```

How can I merge `$this->images` and `$this->thumbnail` in my `Article` model to get the same results that I do in my `Image` model? Meaning that the results are merged with no duplicates.

Many thanks.

**Update:**

Since Razor made me realized that `$this->thumbnail` did not in fact return a collection, but rather a single object it made me rethink if `merge` was really the proper function to use.

```
return $this->images->merge($this->thumbnail()->get());
```

This seemed to cause a lot of unnecessary queries, even though I was eager loading.

So I ended up doing this instead:

```
public function getImagesAllAttribute()
{
    $imagesAll = $this->images;
    if ( ! is_null($this->thumbnail)) $imagesAll->add($this->thumbnail);

    return $imagesAll->unique();
}
```

It drastically reduced the number of queries, and the result is the same.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615656/get-array-of-eloquent-models-relations). It may shed some light on how you arrive at your result. What you are trying to do now just won't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$this->thumbnail` is the same as `$this->thumbnail()->first()`, to get a collection, you may try:

```
public function getImagesAllAttribute()
{
    return $this->images->merge($this->thumbnail()->get());
}
```

Comment: This works! And makes perfect sense (now that you pointed it out). Thanks for this :)

Comment: Didn't even know about this! Thanks!