# Load all relationships for a model

Tags: php, laravel

Usually to eager load a relationship I would do something like this:

`Model::with('foo', 'bar', 'baz')...`

A solution might be to set `$with = ['foo','bar','baz']` however that will always load these three relations whenever I call `Model`

Is it possible to do something like this: `Model::with('*')`?

Comment: I think that Laravel will load all relationships for a certain model, provided that they are defined via the __has__ methods.

Comment: Experience this. I wanted to update cached company relation. This is how is solved. created actions to update specific relations. Every time i create/update a relation i update the cached company.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

No it's not, at least not without some additional work, because your model doesn't know which relations it supports until they are actually loaded.

I had this problem in one of my own Laravel packages. There is no way to get a list of the relations of a model with Laravel. It's pretty obvious though if you look at how they are defined. Simple functions which return a `Relation` object. You can't even get the return type of a function with php's reflection classes, so there is no way to distinguish between a relation function and any other function.

What you can do to make it easier is defining a function that adds all the relationships.
To do this you can use [eloquents query scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes) (Thanks to Jarek Tkaczyk for mentioning it in the comments).

```
public function scopeWithAll($query) 
{
    $query->with('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
}
```

Using scopes instead of static functions allows you to not only use your function directly on the model but for example also when chaining query builder methods like `where` in any order:

```
Model::where('something', 'Lorem ipsum dolor')->withAll()->where('somethingelse', '>', 10)->get();
```

### Alternatives to get supported relations

Although Laravel does not support something like that out of the box you can allways add it yourself.

#### Annotations

I used annotations to determine if a function is a relation or not in my package mentioned above. Annotations are not officially part of php but a lot of people use doc blocks to simulate them.
Laravel 5 is going to use annotations in its route definitions too so I figuered it not to be bad practice in this case. The advantage is, that you don't need to maintain a seperate list of supported relations.

Add an annotation to each of your relations:

```
/**
 * @Relation
 */
public function foo() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Foo');
}
```

And write a function that parses the doc blocks of all methods in the model and returns the name. You can do this in a model or in a parent class:

```
public static function getSupportedRelations() 
{
    $relations = [];
    $reflextionClass = new ReflectionClass(get_called_class());

    foreach($reflextionClass->getMethods() as $method) 
    {
        $doc = $method->getDocComment();

        if($doc && strpos($doc, '@Relation') !== false) 
        {
            $relations[] = $method->getName();
        }
    }

    return $relations;
}
```

And then just use them in your `withAll` function:

```
public function scopeWithAll($query) 
{
    $query->with($this->getSupportedRelations());
}
```

Some like annotations in php and some don't. I like it for this simple use case.

#### Array of supported relations

You can also maintain an array of all the supported relations. This however needs you to always sync it with the available relations which, especially if there are multiple developers involved, is not allways that easy.

```
protected $supportedRelations = ['foo','bar', 'baz'];
```

And then just use them in your `withAll` function:

```
public function scopeWithAll($query) 
{
    return $query->with($this->supportedRelations);
}
```

You can of course also [override `with` like lukasgeiter mentioned in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27742797/983992). This seems cleaner than using `withAll`. If you use annotations or a config array however is a matter of opinion.

Comment: If method will not be static, we can't use like Model::withAll()

Comment: @DmytroGaliievskyi I usually inject models into my controller so I never work with them statically but I fixed that thanks for the hint.

Comment: It's not the way, use `scope` instead, since it won't let you do: `Model::where(..)->...->withAll()->get()`. However `+` for the annotations.

Comment: @JarekTkaczyk Thanks for noting this, didn't know about scopes, they're pretty cool actually. Updated my answer and of course mentioned you.

Comment: Little bit late to the party, but I think you forgot to return the `$query` inside the scope methods. It is documented like that in the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes)

Comment: @DouwedeHaan edit the answer directly and please don't forget to add a type-hint `Builder` with proper `use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.

Comment: If you've got return type declarations on your method (and I think you should, if you're using PHP7), you could modify your `getSupportedRelations` to check the return type of each method. In that way, you could do away with your annotation.

Comment: Use doctrine and setup eager loading for the required relations

Answer (score 5):

There's no way to know what all the relations are without specifying them yourself. How the other answers posted are good, but I wanted to add a few things.

### Base Model

I kind of have the feeling that you want to do this in multiple models, so at first I'd create a `BaseModel` if you haven't already.

```
class BaseModel extends Eloquent {
    public $allRelations = array();
}
```

### "Config" array

Instead of hard coding the relationships into a method I suggest you use a member variable. As you can see above I already added `$allRelations`. Be aware that you can't name it `$relations` since Laravel already uses that internally.

### Override `with()`

Since you wanted `with(*)` you can do that too. Add this to the `BaseModel`

```
public static function with($relations){
    $instance = new static;
    if($relations == '*'){
        $relations = $instance->allRelations;
    }
    else if(is_string($relations)){
        $relations = func_get_args();
    }
    return $instance->newQuery()->with($relations);
}
```

(By the way, some parts of this function come from the original Model class)

### Usage

```
class MyModel extends BaseModel {
    public $allRelations = array('foo', 'bar');
}

MyModel::with('*')->get();
```

Comment: Yes, you're right I did want to use it on multiple models. I used `$relationships` instead of `$relations` before I read your answer and got everything to work fine. I was digging through the Model class documentation and I'm still confused at what `$relations` is supposed to be used for...

Comment: `$relationships` works too that's right. Laravel uses `$relations` to store the relations after they get loaded.

Comment: Mind that it won't affect `with` method on the `Eloquent\Builder`, so you won't be able to do: `Model::where(..)->with('*')->get()`

Comment: Who downvoted this? "*not perfect*" is in my opinion not equal to "*not useful*" or "*wrong*" and thus far away from providing a reason to downvote... (It's not even my answer)

Comment: @MarcelGwerder I don't know and can't really understand it either. Your answer is looking better though (with the stuff you added afterwards) +1

Answer (score 4):

Since i've met with a similar problem, and found a good solution that isn't described here and doesn't require filling some custom arrays or whatever, i'll post it for the future.

What i do, is first create a `trait`, called `RelationsManager`:

```
trait RelationsManager
{
    protected static $relationsList = [];

    protected static $relationsInitialized = false;

    protected static $relationClasses = [
        HasOne::class,
        HasMany::class,
        BelongsTo::class,
        BelongsToMany::class
    ];

    public static function getAllRelations($type = null) : array
    {
        if (!self::$relationsInitialized) {
            self::initAllRelations();
        }

        return $type ? (self::$relationsList[$type] ?? []) : self::$relationsList;
    }

    protected static function initAllRelations()
    {
        self::$relationsInitialized = true;

        $reflect = new ReflectionClass(static::class);

        foreach($reflect->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC) as $method) {
            /** @var ReflectionMethod $method */
            if ($method->hasReturnType() && in_array((string)$method->getReturnType(), self::$relationClasses)) {
                self::$relationsList[(string)$method->getReturnType()][] = $method->getName();
            }
        }
    }

    public static function withAll() : Builder
    {
        $relations = array_flatten(static::getAllRelations());

        return $relations ? self::with($relations) : self::query();
    }
}
```

Now you can use it with any class, like -

```
class Project extends Model
{
    use RelationsManager;

    //... some relations

}
```

and then when you need to fetch them from the database:

```
$projects = Project::withAll()->get();
```

Some notes - my example relation classes list doesn't include morph relations, so if you want to get them as well - you need to add them to `$relationClasses` variable. Also, this solution only works with PHP 7.

Comment: mmm, its return an empty array `[]`

Comment: instead of `in_array((string)$method->getReturnType(), self::$relationClasses)` 
I use 
`is_a($classString, Relation::class,true)`
Becuase all  relationClasses extend the Realtion::class this works

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use `static` methods like suggested since... it's Eloquent ;) 
Just leverage what it already offers - **a scope**.

Of course it won't do it for you (the main question), however this is definitely the way to go:

```
// SomeModel
public function scopeWithAll($query)
{
    $query->with([ ... all relations here ... ]); 
    // or store them in protected variable - whatever you prefer
    // the latter would be the way if you want to have the method
    // in your BaseModel. Then simply define it as [] there and use:
    // $query->with($this->allRelations); 
}
```

This way you're free to use this as you like:

```
// static-like
SomeModel::withAll()->get();

// dynamically on the eloquent Builder
SomeModel::query()->withAll()->get();
SomeModel::where('something', 'some value')->withAll()->get();
```

---

Also, in fact you **can** let Eloquent do it for you, just like `Doctrine` does - using `doctrine/annotations` and DocBlocks. You could do something like this:

```
// SomeModel

/**
 * @Eloquent\Relation
 */
public function someRelation()
{
  return $this->hasMany(..);
}
```

It's a bit too long story to include it here, so learn how it works: http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html

Answer (score 2):

You could attempt to detect the methods specific to your model using reflection, such as:

```
$base_methods = get_class_methods('Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model');
$model_methods = get_class_methods(get_class($entry));
$maybe_relations = array_diff($model_methods, $base_methods);

dd($maybe_relations);
```

Then attempt to load each in a well-controlled `try/catch`. The **Model** class of Laravel has a **load** and a **loadMissing** methods for eager loading.

See the [api reference.](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can create method in your Model

```
public static function withAllRelations() {
   return static::with('foo', 'bar', 'baz');
}
```

And call `Model::withAllRelations()`

Or

`$instance->withAllRelations()->first(); // or ->get()`

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a **dynamic** loading of relationships for a certain model. you need to tell the model which relations to support.

Answer (score 0):

composer require adideas/laravel-get-relationship-eloquent-model

https://packagist.org/packages/adideas/laravel-get-relationship-eloquent-model

Laravel get relationship all eloquent models!

You don't need to know the names of the methods in the model to do this. Having one or many Eloquent models, thanks to this package, you can get all of its relationships and their type at runtime

Answer (score 0):

**The Best Solution**

first create a trait, called RelationsManager:

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasManyThrough;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneThrough;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphMany;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphToMany;
use ReflectionClass;
use ReflectionMethod;

trait RelationsManager
{
    protected static $relationsList = [];

    protected static $relationsInitialized = false;

    protected static $relationClasses = [
        HasOne::class,
        HasMany::class,
        BelongsTo::class,
        BelongsToMany::class,

        HasOneThrough::class,
        HasManyThrough::class,

        MorphTo::class,
        MorphOne::class,
        MorphMany::class,
        MorphToMany::class,

    ];

    public static function getAllRelations($type = null): array
    {
        if (!self::$relationsInitialized) {
            self::initAllRelations();
        }

        return $type ? (self::$relationsList[$type] ?? []) : self::$relationsList;
    }

    protected static function initAllRelations()
    {
        self::$relationsInitialized = true;

        $reflect = new ReflectionClass(static::class);

        foreach ($reflect->getMethods(ReflectionMethod::IS_PUBLIC) as $method) {
            /** @var ReflectionMethod $method */
            if ($method->hasReturnType() && in_array((string) $method->getReturnType(), self::$relationClasses)) {
                self::$relationsList[(string) $method->getReturnType()][] = $method->getName();
            }
        }
    }

    public static function withAll(): Builder
    {
        $relations = array_flatten(static::getAllRelations());
        return $relations ? self::with($relations) : self::query();
    }
}
```

Now you can use it with any class, like -

```
class Company extends Model
{
    use RelationsManager;

    //... some relations

}
```

and then when you need to fetch them from the database:

```
$companies = Company::withAll()->get();
```

this solution only works with PHP 7 Or Higher.

**Done**