# How to get a part of a belongsTo relationship in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have a model called `Log`. It has a foreign key called `hash_id`, and a `belongsTo` relationship to `App\Hash`.

I understand that I can retrieve the corresponding hash entry by calling `Log::with('hash')` as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21615656/get-array-of-eloquent-models-relations). What I'd like to do is retrieve specific rows of the corresponding hash column instead of every one of them. So something like `Log::with('hash', ['only' => 'name'])`. This is because I'm sending the data over AJAX, and don't want to send a lot of unnecessary columns with it. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do by two ways

using anonymous function

```
Log::with(['hash' => function($query) { 
    return $query->select('id','text');
}])->get();
```

second way

```
  Log::with('hash:id,text')->get();
```

> Remember one thing you will need to select relational columns or else
>   it will not work

more information read this [article](https://binbytes.com/blog/laravel-eager-loading-with-selected-columns)

Comment: It works, but stops working when I combine it with `select`. How can I achieve `Log::with('hash:id,text')->select('log')->first()`? As this turns `hash` null.

Comment: @Mav u need to select also relational columns in parent table otherwise it wiill give you null data..(i also mention in answer dear)

Answer (score 1):

You have to write all the columns with a `:`

```
Log::with('hash:id,text')
```

This would return only the id and the text.

*As a sidenote: You need to select the foreign key, otherwise the relation is empty*

[Here you can read more about it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)